# How can I add content of one section in some other section on click of a button using DOM. Like adding some dishes to a fav section

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, dom, attributes

[image]

[image]

My 'add tofav' button is working in console But I don't know how to add the dishes to the Fav section that in the open collapsible.

```
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
    <div class="content">
    <p>dskshf</p>
    </div>
```

The content of the Open collapsible are hidden and i want to add the dishes to here.

```
const fetchMeal = async (query) => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${query}`);
  const response2 = await response.json();
  response2.meals.forEach(meal => {
    const newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.classList.add('recipe');
    newdiv.innerHTML = `
    <img src = "${meal.strMealThumb}">
    <h2>${meal.strMeal}</h2>
    <p>${meal.strCategory} </p>

/* MAIN PART OF THE QUESTION*/
const FavBtn = document.createElement('button');
  FavBtn.textContent = "Add tofavs";
  newdiv.appendChild(FavBtn);
  FavBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
     //console.log("working");
    addRemoveToFavList(meal);
  });
```

How should I proceed with the addRemovetofavlist function?

CSS:

```
.collapsible {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 10%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #c9a5a5;
  }
  /* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

I tried the to do list approach by document.createElemnt but it do not work.

Comment: What do you want to add to the "favourites," the whole recipe, or some means to navigate back to that recipe?

Comment: I want to add only the dish Name and photo of it using the meal db api.